# How to add Polygon coordinates to an existing geoJSON file?

Tags: leaflet, polygon

Trying to place the boundaries of 42 countries to the map with Choropleth Leaflet. Apparently, the data that I have only had lat and long for each country and not the list of coordinates. How would I add polygon coordinates to my existing data? Or is there an API I can use for that? Research brought me nowhere.

my data

````
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "country": "Austria",
        "points": 89.19089810712848,
        "price": 31.192106322996377
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          13.199959,
          47.2000338
        ]
      }```
````

Answer (score 1):

If you need rough country border coordinates, you can search for "GeoJSON world", there are a few convenient sources available.

For example https://geojson-maps.ash.ms/, https://github.com/simonepri/geo-maps or https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json